# Paypal Buy now button without shipping anything?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a buy now (pay now) button but when a user pays, I'll get a notification that the user pays but i can't get the money unless i shipped the item to the User.

I don't have items to be shipped! I want the button to be something like the donation button, if someone pays i get the money immediately.

But I don't want **DONATIONS**, I am actually using the **pay now** and **NOT** the **buy now** button so there's nothing to buy, but you pay for **something** like a VIP service

I don't want to use the subscription button because I want the user to pay as many times as he wants, the more times he pays the more service he gets.

So how can i get the money from the **pay now** without having to deliver any items?

**Update**

**@BillyMoon** I am actually giving something but not a physical item you know - i don't know how to explain it, like when you buy chips from facebook zinga poker game, the user can pay many times and get more chips.

or like when you pay on facebook to advertise something there, you can pay many times if you want to have many ads, I can give you guys many examples!!

Haven't you played any games, or paid to any service, where you get something, but not a physical item?

**@Robert**

I host a competition on my site, if you pay 3$, you'll get a chance to enter the competition, if you pay twice you'll get more chance of winning, you can subscribe to my site without paying but you won't be entering the competition and you won't have a chance to win (i don't want to give more details until I launch the site) but you see the main idea

I was testing the buy now button so i made the value of it 0.10$ (which is the minimum value possible) just for testing coz i am from lebanon, not allowed to use and don't know how to use sandbox

so i paid twice, just to see if everything is working so i should receive 0.20$ right?

i go to my paypal, I can see that i paid twice but the money wasn't added to my paypal let me show you, I had 0.86$ before i paid to this account. but this amount didn't increase [image]

Although I received the payments, my paypal balance is still the same

Comment: I want to know how to get people to give me money without giving them something too... let me know if you find the formula.

Comment: @BillyMoon I am actually giving something but not a physical item you know - i don't know how to explain it, like when you buy chips from facebook poker game

Comment: I have a PayPal solution where I sell PDF documents. I dont ship anything, so this is posible. I will look at my settings (flags) and post it for you.

Comment: @Eystein i am not selling downloads- what is your solution anyway sir? payloadz? e-junkie? or something else

Comment: payloadz, e-junkie are not the solution I'm looking for

Comment: I dont know payloadz or e-junkie. I use PayPal! The user pays via PayPal. When PayPal accepted the payment, they confirm this by calling a webpage on my server with the payment-token. I then send the user the PDF-file or what ever else they payed for.

Comment: @Eystein you give me an example that i can see using php sir?

Comment: I think sending them a pdf by email, or whatever else you send them _is_ the shipment. I don't think it needs to be physical. You could go so far as to make the receipt the shipment.

Comment: @BillyMoon I think that you are right, i was testing my system live (not on sandbox) so i send 0.10$ just to see if it works, and now i remember that paypal fee is 0.10$, this might be the reason why I'm not getting money

Comment: Yes, what you want is possible and not a problem to set up. What exactly is your problem? You've described your usecase, but you haven't described the exact problem you're running into.

Comment: (And no, this has nothing to do with the PayPal fee. Post what you have right now and I can point out where your error lies).

Comment: You did get the money. It's 'Completed'. You can press 'Details' to see how much PayPal charged you in fees.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turn off shipping address collection by setting no_shipping to '1'.
This will remove the 'Print shipping label' option, and not include the shipping address for you.
A billing address will still be required on the credit card entry screen (obviously).

Set `<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">`

Comment: As of today, HTML code for "Pay Now" buttons generated via PayPal web tool no longer produce that <input> line.